# deleting image from a file in php

Tags: php, unlink

I am trying to delete a file from folder in php here is my model function

```
function deleteFiles()
    {
        $file = "http://localhost/copycopy/img/uploaded/long.jpeg";
            if(is_file($file))
            {
                @unlink($file); // delete file
                echo $file.'file deleted';
            }
            else
            {
                echo "no file";
            } 
    }
```

but I always see "no file" and file is never deleted, file is in folder,because the url in $file actually displays the file in browser
help me

Comment: Are you sure that you can pass a URL to `is_file`? Have you tried passing a the fully qualified path to the function instead?

Comment: how to pass that? could you please give an example

Comment: like `/var/www/copycopy/img/uploaded/long.jpeg` - `is_file` is using the local filesystem.

Comment: You're trying to remove a URL. That's not permitted, and would be highly dangerous in any case. unlink() will try to do it vi an HTTP request, meaning that someone who knew your server allows delete-via-http, could totally kill your site by issuing delete calls for ALL your content.

Comment: What does `@` do? Oh yeah, I remember, it suppresses error messages that would otherwise help you diagnose your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using web url

```
$file = "http://localhost/copycopy/img/uploaded/long.jpeg";
```

use local path to file:

```
$file = $pathToYourWebSite . "/copycopy/img/uploaded/long.jpeg";
```

be sure to set $pathToYourWebSite to real location of your website;